# Searching by hitting enter

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Right now i have a search field and right next to it a submit search button. 
But want to delete the button so that the user can just hit enter. What do i need to change ?

```
 <%= form_tag search_path, method: :get do %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "z.B. New York", class: "suchfeld", id: "autolocation" %>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-normal btn-block" %>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <br/><br/>


<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done using jquery or javascript

1 -> Provide a unique id to form and input field which will be submitted on hit enter

```
 <%= form_tag(search_path, method: :get, id: 'search_form') do %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "z.B. New York", class: "suchfeld", id: "autolocation" %>
    </div>    
  </div>
  <br/><br/>
<% end %>
```

2 -> Using jQuery  check if enter button is pressed, then submit this form

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#autolocation').keydown(function(event) {
    // enter has keyCode = 13
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      $('#search_form')submit(); // submit the form
      return false;
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple hide the button using css. `{display: none}`. But don't delete the button. (If you are using boostrap try adding `d-none` class to the submit button.) This will submit your form with enter key.

Comment: We should ask why the OP wants to be mouse-hostile. The user should always have a choice...